# Can snmpreceiver or pysnmp module be used to collect data for a printer monitoring system using django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fault, pysnmp, network-printers

i am trying to generate SNMP data for printers for later analysis using a prediction algorithm to be able to fortell emanating faults in printers before they actually occur. I seek advice on how best i could collect the data and prepare it in a dataset format like .csv so as to feed it into my classifier.

Would really appreciate any help rendered

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My approach might not be the most efficient one but it is possible to start with and later improve it.

What I would do in your case would be the following:

1) Create a python script that polls every printer, you need to poll. This using Pysnmp.

2) What I don't understand is where you want to collect your data from but anyways, you can import csv in your poller script and create a csv file if that is what you want. Or if you want that data inserted into a sql database eg MySQL you can push the data as well from your script.

Hope this helps:)